# Using ruby in WSH (Windows Scripting Host)

Tags: ruby, windows, wsh

Has anyone experience with using ruby in WSH (Windows Scripting Host)?
The following doesn't work, Ruby is installed on the system.

```
<package id = "hello_world">  
<job>
<script language="VBScript">
  MsgBox "hello world (from vb)"
</script>
<script language="JScript">
  WSH.echo("hello world (from js)");
</script>
<script language="RubyScript">
  puts "hello world (from ruby)"
</script>
</job>
</package>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard ruby does not contain/install an ActiveScript engine. You could try:

[ActiveScriptRuby](http://www.artonx.org/data/asr/index.html)

I did a test install (Windows XP) and the basics 'did work' - YMMV.